# Вывод всех пользователей через R::loadAll - RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

мне нужно вывести все данные пользователей, которые есть в таблице users.
Я могу вывести просто по несколько определенных, если указать в $ids определенные числа с id. В данном случае я вывожу только 5 пользователей. Как реализовать вывод всех пользователей, не указав определенный id. (Автоматизировать)

'''

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
$users_all = R::loadAll('users', $ids);

foreach ($users_all as $user){
    echo $user->login.' ';
}
```

'''

Comment: А что если попробовать выбрать все идентификаторы пользователей ```$ids = R::getCol('SELECT `id` FROM users')```?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил проблему и разобрался как это всё работает, надо было сделать так: 
```

$users_all = R::find('users'); foreach ($users_all as $user){ echo $user->id.' '; echo $user->login.' '.'<br>'; }

```